# Late answers with the same concept as the previous ones are marked as accepted, Why?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Sometimes I answer a question; and later some other user read the question and its related answers, reformulate them with better English, or group all other answer's concepts in one solution, and this way they get their answer accepted.

Why don't authors take the response timing in consideration?  I faced this many times, and I feel that this is not fair.

This is an example: [Laravel 5.5 Method update doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382498/laravel-5-5-method-update-doesnt-exist/48382624#48382624)

Please note the answers time-stamps.

Comment: Because the OP is free to accept whatever answer they want?

Comment: And in that particular case, the accepted answer is slightly better and more complete than yours.

Comment: @yivi, I think you don't understand my question, I'm not asking to force OP choose an answer here, and Of course his solution is better because he took both answer's ideas and create another one after 2 hours

Comment: If you would have added some explanation to your answer it would have had a better chance of being accepted.

Comment: Unless there is some actual plagiarism occurring there is nothing to do with similar answers beyond voting on them.

Comment: "_Why don't authors take the response timing in consideration?_" Why should they?

Answer (score 17):

Accepting an answer is the OP prerogative, an they can accept **any answer they feel it helped them the most**.

As voting, it is a personal privilege and can't be contested unless there is a case of abuse.

Going beyond the "the OP is free to do what they want with their acceptance mark", timing in answers is not relevant at all to determine an answer's helpfulness or quality.

While *fast* answers are nice, *great* answers are way better.

And *better* answers stand a greater chance to be more useful to the questioner, and from that it follows that they are more likely to be accepted.

(Or not, because no matter what **the questioner is free to accept any answer they want**. The check-mark supposed to signify "this answer helped me the most", but we can't force anyone's choice, nor read anyone's mind.)

Also, please try not to tell users things like this:

> [image: Unhelpful comment]

That is simply not true, and you should not try to teach new users to value promptness over quality or thoroughness.

In the linked example, I do not think the accepted answer is really ripping off the ideas posted on previous answers, as posting a more complete version of a very simple answer.

This could serve to encourage you to post more in-depth answers in the future instead of quickly dumping a few lines of code.

I do not think your answer is bad in any way (and you've already got more points thanks to votes than the accepted answer did), but you could have spent a couple more minutes writing an explanation that is not only more useful for the OP, but generally speaking more useful for future readers.

Comment: There is a lot of truth in here, but it must be stressed that in reality acceptance has nothing to do with quality; that is what votes are for. The only thing it signifies is how helpful it was to the questioner.

Comment: Yup, that's what my first paragraph says. Still, I can only hope _some_ correlation exists between quality and helpfulness in regards to the questioner. In the linked example, bare as it is, the questioner seems to have accepted the better answer, IMO.

Comment: Let me be more specific: lines such as "While fast answers are nice, great answers are way better." are quite distracting as they really have nothing to do with what you're trying to say in your answer.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks, but I do not quite agree. The questioner here is attributing _timing_ in answers a value that should weight in questioners accepting one answer over the other, and I'm trying to address that point: fast is nice, but good is better (and _better_ is hopefully expected to be more useful to the questioner as well). I guess I can try to rephrase that a bit if it's not clear enough.

Comment: Some might think that the earlier answers were from posters who are not in the voting ring.  I could not possibly comment myself.